# Changing the screen resolution from Qt?

Tags: windows, qt

I'd like to change the screen resolution and then go fullscreen with one activex control (a flash player). Obviously, a windows-only solution is fine :). Is there a Qt api for that, or do I need to dig into winapi? If so, where do I look (keywords)?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If your app would change my screen resolution I'd definitively not use it! Why do you need that?

Comment: It will run on a special machine designated for this one app. The flash program it executes wouldn't run at an acceptable performance at higher resolution. Don't ask me why they can't change the resolution from the OS and keep it that way. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There isn't a Qt API for that. You'll need to use the Windows API. See [ChangeDisplaySettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183411%28VS.85%29.aspx)