# How to change screen resolution using QT, OpenGL, C++, and Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, opengl

I just want to make a full screen game. I know how to change resolution on Windows but how do I change the resolution under Linux? Is there a cross platform QT solution for this? Also I've got borders around my GLWidget. How do I make the widget cover the entire window?

I'm just going to post the code:

```
#include <QtOpenGL>

class GLWidget : public QGLWidget
{
public:
    void initializeGL()
    {
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        glClearDepth(1.0f);
    }

    void paintGL()
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }

    void resizeGL(int width, int height)
    {
        int side = qMin(width, height);
        glViewport((width - side) / 2, (height - side) / 2, side, side);
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(-0.5f, +0.5f, -0.5f, +0.5f, 4.0f, 15.0f);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QDesktopWidget *desktop = app.desktop();
    QWidget window;
    GLWidget *glWidget = new GLWidget;
    QHBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    mainLayout->addWidget(glWidget);
    window.setLayout(mainLayout);
    window.setWindowTitle("Hello GL");
    window.resize(QSize(640, 480));
    window.show();
    window.showFullScreen();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: SDL is probably a better toolkit for games than Qt.

Comment: Take a look at [xrandr](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Xorg_RandR_1.2).

Comment: Someone [already asked this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372252/changing-the-screen-resolution-from-qt).

Comment: Actually that's on windows. That does not provide an answer to my question. My best guess is that I need to use x window api to do it. However, this begs the question of why not just use the platform window library in the first place if I'm going to have to use it anyway?

Also I really need to know how to remove the borders from the glwidget.

Comment: Setting the layout margins seem to fix the border problem but I'm not sure if that is the best way to do it. Is there anyway I can render directly to the window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [xrrsetscreenconfigandrate](http://linux.die.net/man/3/xrrsetscreenconfigandrate), as explained [here](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Programming_OpenGL_in_Linux%3a_Changing_the_Screen_Resolution):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<X11/Xlib.h>
#include<X11/extensions/Xrandr.h>

Display                 *dpy;
Window                  root;
int                     num_sizes;
XRRScreenSize           *xrrs;
XRRScreenConfiguration  *conf;
short                   possible_frequencies[64][64];
short                   original_rate;
Rotation                original_rotation;
SizeID                  original_size_id;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
 //
 //     CONNECT TO X-SERVER, GET ROOT WINDOW ID
 //
 dpy    = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
 root   = RootWindow(dpy, 0);
 //
 //     GET POSSIBLE SCREEN RESOLUTIONS
 //
 xrrs   = XRRSizes(dpy, 0, &num_sizes);
 //
 //     LOOP THROUGH ALL POSSIBLE RESOLUTIONS,
 //     GETTING THE SELECTABLE DISPLAY FREQUENCIES
 //
 for(int i = 0; i < num_sizes; i ++) {
        short   *rates;
        int     num_rates;

        printf("\n\t%2i : %4i x %4i   (%4imm x%4imm ) ", i, xrrs[i].width, xrrs[i].height, xrrs[i].mwidth, xrrs[i].mheight);

        rates = XRRRates(dpy, 0, i, &num_rates);

        for(int j = 0; j < num_rates; j ++) {
                possible_frequencies[i][j] = rates[j];
                printf("%4i ", rates[j]); } }

 printf("\n");
 //
 //     GET CURRENT RESOLUTION AND FREQUENCY
 //
 conf                   = XRRGetScreenInfo(dpy, root);
 original_rate          = XRRConfigCurrentRate(conf);
 original_size_id       = XRRConfigCurrentConfiguration(conf, &original_rotation);

 printf("\n\tCURRENT SIZE ID  : %i\n", original_size_id);
 printf("\tCURRENT ROTATION : %i \n", original_rotation);
 printf("\tCURRENT RATE     : %i Hz\n\n", original_rate);
 //
 //     CHANGE RESOLUTION
 //
 printf("\tCHANGED TO %i x %i PIXELS, %i Hz\n\n", xrrs[1].width, xrrs[1].height, possible_frequencies[1][0]);
 XRRSetScreenConfigAndRate(dpy, conf, root, 1, RR_Rotate_0, possible_frequencies[1][0], CurrentTime);
 //
 //     SLEEP A WHILE
 //
 usleep(6000000);
 //
 //     RESTORE ORIGINAL CONFIGURATION
 //
 printf("\tRESTORING %i x %i PIXELS, %i Hz\n\n", xrrs[original_size_id].width, xrrs[original_size_id].height, original_rate);
 XRRSetScreenConfigAndRate(dpy, conf, root, original_size_id, original_rotation, original_rate, CurrentTime);
 //
 //     EXIT
 //
 XCloseDisplay(dpy); }
//
//      gcc -o Xrandr Xrandr.cc -lX11 -lXrandr -lstdc++
//
```

Comment: That appears to be the best solution. Thank you fine sir!