# How can i get screen resolution in c (Operating system QNX or Linux)

Tags: c

I am in a GUI development with QNX(screen resolution interdependent design)
How can i get screen resolution in c.
I am using QNX operating system.
Is it possible?
Is any OS function for this solution?

thanks

Comment: What graphics library are you using?

Comment: Not sure but may be it will help in your case

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387724/how-to-change-screen-resolution-using-qt-opengl-c-and-linux

Answer (score 4):

Assume you are using a device with a framebuffer (and have root access):
(taken from this answer: [Paint Pixels to Screen via Linux FrameBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996777/paint-pixels-to-screen-via-linux-framebuffer))

Also, as mentioned above, what graphics library you are using will make a lot of difference as this code will only tell you what the framebuffer is set to and not what the GUI code is using. So might not be useful at all. If you are not using X or any other graphics library, then you will probably need to be using the framebuffer, and you can see the rest of the answer for how to do that. (I strongly suggest you use DirectFB this will save you implementing a LOT of code).

Also, you could also use the gl drivers that turn up on most devices (inc. embedded ones) so this will also effect how you do what you require.

Are you using a SOC? Does the manufacturer have there own driver layer? That may work completely different and would probably come with it's own API to handle this.

But anyway, I hope this helps.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/fb.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

int main()
{
    int fbfd = 0;
    struct fb_var_screeninfo vinfo;
    struct fb_fix_screeninfo finfo;
    long int screensize = 0;
    char *fbp = 0;
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    long int location = 0;

    // Open the file for reading and writing
    fbfd = open("/dev/fb0", O_RDWR);
    if (fbfd == -1) {
        perror("Error: cannot open framebuffer device");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("The framebuffer device was opened successfully.\n");

    // Get fixed screen information
    if (ioctl(fbfd, FBIOGET_FSCREENINFO, &finfo) == -1) {
        perror("Error reading fixed information");
        exit(2);
    }

    // Get variable screen information
    if (ioctl(fbfd, FBIOGET_VSCREENINFO, &vinfo) == -1) {
        perror("Error reading variable information");
        exit(3);
    }

    printf("%dx%d, %dbpp\n", vinfo.xres, vinfo.yres, vinfo.bits_per_pixel);

    // Figure out the size of the screen in bytes
    //
    close(fbfd);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For a unix-like OS, you may use the library X11, but if you need cross-platform solution, try the GTK+.

**A full code**

```
// The C standart library
#include <stdlib.h>

// GTK+
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <glib/gprintf.h>

// X11
#include <X11/Xlib.h>


/*
    Printing a current screen resoltion by using the GTK+3
    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GTK%2B
 */
int
print_screen_resolution_by_GTK(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GdkScreen *screen;
    gint width, height;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    if ((screen = gdk_screen_get_default()) != NULL) {
        width = gdk_screen_get_width(screen);
        height = gdk_screen_get_height(screen);
        g_printf("Current screen resolution: %dx%d (by used GTK+)\n", width, height);
    }
    return 0;
}


/*
    Printing a current screen resoltion by using the libX11 (worked only for Unix-like OS)
    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System

    Based on:
        https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/libX11/specs/libX11/libX11.html
        http://surfingtroves.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-get-screen-resolution-in-linux-c.html
 */
int
print_display_resolution_by_X11()
{
    Display *display;
    Window window;
    XWindowAttributes xw_attrs;

    if ((display = XOpenDisplay(NULL)) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open default display\n");
        return -1;
    }

    window = DefaultRootWindow(display);

    XGetWindowAttributes(display, window, &xw_attrs);

    printf("Current window resolution: %dx%d (by used X11)\n", xw_attrs.width, xw_attrs.height);

    XCloseDisplay(display);

    return 0;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    print_screen_resolution_by_GTK(argc, argv);
    print_display_resolution_by_X11();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**A compilation**

```
gcc -o main main.c `pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-3.0 x11`
```

**A result** (actual for my computer)

```
Current screen resolution: 1366x768 (by used GTK+)
Current window resolution: 1366x768 (by used X11)
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can simply use this function I created, it get screen size from your configuration files, split it, and then return 2 values (resolution as x and y)**

I tried it on Ubuntu 20.04 and it works perfectly !

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned short *get_screen_size(void)
{
    static unsigned short size[2];
    char *array[8];
    char screen_size[64];
    char* token = NULL;

    FILE *cmd = popen("xdpyinfo | awk '/dimensions/ {print $2}'", "r");

    if (!cmd)
        return 0;

    while (fgets(screen_size, sizeof(screen_size), cmd) != NULL);
    pclose(cmd);

    token = strtok(screen_size, "x\n");

    if (!token)
        return 0;

    for (unsigned short i = 0; token != NULL; ++i) {
        array[i] = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, "x\n");
    }
    size[0] = atoi(array[0]);
    size[1] = atoi(array[1]);
    size[2] = -1;

    return size;
}


int main(void)
{
    unsigned short *size = get_screen_size();

    printf("Screen resolution = %dx%d\n", size[0], size[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

If you have any question, do not hesitate ! :)